# FileExplorer syntax for file search when filename contains hyphens

Tags: windows-10, windows-explorer, search

Using the Win 10 FileExplorer, I want to find "myfile-2015-info.pdf" while knowing for sure only "myfile-2015".  If I enter `file:myfile` it is in the (long) list, so I keep typing and `file:myfile-2015` fails completely.  The hyphen is the problem.  Why is it a problem (with NO space preceding)? Putting the search in quotes does not help. It turns out that `file:~myfile-2015` works nicely, but why does the tilde help? I looked at the AQS page and could not find an answer.  Where can I find decent enough documentation of FileExplorer quirks that I could anticipate all this?  My GoogleFu is usually decent but I searched the Microsoft site without joy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found the [Microsoft documentation of the basic query syntax](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb266512(v=vs.85).aspx#query_strings).  The tilde apparently does string matching with wild cards. Variations include `~<` for "starts with, `~>` for "ends with".  (Search on `COP_DOSWILDCARDS` for details.)

Answer (score 0):

The tilde ~ seems to return files that start with the search word, try **file:python** then **file:~python** for example. Windows search seems also to ignore spaces and hyphens try **file:python** then **file:python 2**, both return the same files. Try the **?** (any single character) operator so **file:~myfile?2015**. To search for certain file types try adding the **ext:** keyword, **file:python?2 ext:pdf** (note the space separator before ext:).

More info [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa965711(v=vs.85).aspx).

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks but as stated in the question I've already looked at the AQS page and it does not answer my questions.  I would love to know about documentation that does.

Answer (score 0):

Use: **`name:~"myfile-2015*"`**

Similar to searching for parentheses:

[image: ScreenShot of Explorer Search for parentheses]

Comment: Thanks but that solution is already in the body of the question.

Comment: You are mistaken. Note the use of the tilde & the quotes.  Most importantly, did you test before commenting/?

Comment: Quotation marks allow characters such as -. ~, [, ], (, ) to be interpreted as literals, whereas the initial ':~ ' tells Search to allow wildcards within the quoted string.

Comment: Look again.  The body of the question notes that I can get what I want with a tilde.  The question is: Where can I find decent enough documentation of FileExplorer quirks that I could anticipate all this?  I.e., the question is a documentation request.